# Convert np array of type (n, ) into a pandas dataframe of type (n,1)

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I have the following np array:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
```

It has the following shape - (n, ). I need to convert it into pandas dataframe of type (n,1). Please, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.DataFrame()` function. Details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(array,col=['col_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.expand_dims` to expand the dimension of your array.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is x then use df = pd.DataFrame(x) although a dataframe with one column is the same as s = pd.Series(x)